# Messenger bot answer speed issue

Tags: php, heroku, facebook-messenger

I don't know if only I have this issue, but there is serious problem with my messenger bot.
It is built in php straight forward:

```
$accessToken =   "EAxxxxxxxxxxxqgBAKWAgizvoHnQLZBR7ZxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxptYSymSdocFFCp1ink3EHRVMrCSxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxwMZApStyA8GbqAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx9R6QttFVyNS4ZBurwZDZD";

$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$senderId = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id'];
$messageText = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text'];
$response = null;
//set Message
if($messageText == "hi") {
    $answer = "Hello";
}
//send message to facebook bot
$response = [
    'recipient' => [ 'id' => $senderId ],
    'message' => [ 'text' => $answer ]
];
$ch = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token='.$accessToken);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($response));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
if(!empty($input)){
$result = curl_exec($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

But it takes 3-5 seconds to reply. Server is in Australia. But when I tried heroku cloud platform with nodeJS it all went smoothly, instant response.
Do you have any idea or suggestions why this is happening? Is nodeJS faster at this point and I should think about making bot in this language or it might be something else?

Comment: yeaah true true

Comment: sorry, removed tag

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to make a direct answer for your question because we can't reproduce your server environment. And I don't really think the physical server location or programming language make such a big delay like several seconds. One thing I recommend you to try is to send a request like ping command from the Heroku server to your server in Australia. Then, at least you can break down the issue into programming/software issue or network issue.